# Logging accurate timestamps in a java multithread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, timestamp, nanotime

How do i make sure that timestamps belonging to certain events are actually created and logged right at the same time that the event happened when multiple threads are running?

```java
class Thread1 extends Thread {
    void run() {
        executeTask1();
        logger.log('Task 1 finished at '+System.nanoTime());
    }
}
class Thread2 extends Thread {
    void run() {
        executeTask2(); // assume Task2 takes 10 seconds
        logger.log('Task 2 finished at '+System.nanoTime());
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread1 thread=new Thread1();
        thread1.start()
        Thread2 thread=new Thread2();
        thread2.start()
    }
}
```

Now the execution order could be like:

```
    executeTask1();
    executeTask2(); // assume Task2 takes 10 seconds
    logger.log('Task 1 finished at '+System.nanoTime());
    logger.log('Task 2 finished at '+System.nanoTime());
```

which would give a wrong time for Task1.
When i use a global lock to do something like

```java
synchronized(lock) {
    executeTask2(); // assume Task2 takes 10 seconds
    logger.log('Task 2 finished at '+System.nanoTime());
}
```

does not make a lot of sense to me, because it is ok if multiple threads execute their tasks concurrently, it's just that the time logging needs to be accurate..
Any help?

Comment: Inside the run() method of thread, you can put your log to track the timestamp. ANother way is once thread completes the operation, you can put your log. This can be done using thread.join() method if my understanding from the question is correct.

Comment: I don’t understand the issue. The call to `System.nanoTime()` happens before the call to `logger.log()`, so will read the correct clock time no matter if it is logged immediately or only after a delay due to log synchronization.

Comment: @OleV.V. the issue is that i need the exact time when Task1 finished and i would get the wrong time with the execution order mentioned above!

Comment: I can’t help you there. Even with only 1 thread in your program, the OS may preempt it between the calls to `executeTask1()` and `System.nanoTime()` so you don’t get the accurate time. It typically won’t be for long though, no matter if you’ve go 1, 2 or 1000 threads.